# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') on React Native

Tags: reactjs, native

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
[image]

Comment: Can you show where you are using `PrescriptionTables` ?

Comment: Very not descriptive. From what I see, the best thing I can suggest to you, is to chain optionally, like navigation?.navigate, it will fix the undefined issue, but won't work as you expect.